# nodejs express Delete and Update not working in for one Component in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

we have a small project and we are integrating our individual components into one. Everything seems to work except for the action to delete a record and update a record. This code worked when it was the individuals element, but when integrated into one app it doesn't seem to be work. The code looks good and it works for the Drivers component but not the Riders. Any insight is GREATLY APPRECIATED.

```
//connecting to MongoDB
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const driver = require('./models/drivers') //specify where to find the schema
const Rider = require('./models/riders')

const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:pass@muleapp-xxxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }) // connect and display the status 
  .then(() => { console.log("connected"); })
  .catch(() => { console.log("error connecting to cluster"); });


// use the following code on any request that matches the specified mount path
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   console.log('This line is always called');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); //can connect from any host
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS'); //allowable methods
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
});


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/jsonn
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

### DRIVERS

```
// calls to the Mongo DB to retrieve drivers
app.get('/drivers', (req, res, next) => 
  driver.find() //call mongoose method find (MongoDB db.driversfind())
    .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))//if data is returned, send data as a response
    //if error, send internal server error
    .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ${err}');
    res.status(500).json(err);

 }));

app.post('/drivers', (req, res, next) => {
   const Driver = new driver({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      email: req.body.email,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      street: req.body.street,
      city: req.body.city,
      zip: req.body.zip,
      year: req.body.year,
      make: req.body.make,
      model: req.body.model,
    });
    //send the document to the database 
    Driver.save()
      //in case of success
      .then(() => { console.log('Success');})
      //if error
      .catch(err => { console.log('Error:' + err);})
   });

//:id is a dynamic parameter that will be extracted from the URL
app.delete("/drivers/:id", (req, res, next) => {
   driver.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(result => {
     console.log(result);
     res.status(200).json("Deleted!");
   });
 });

 // serve incoming put requests to /students
 app.put('/drivers/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("id: " + req.params.id)
  // check that the parameter id is valid 
  if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
    //find a document and set new first and last names
    driver.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},
      {$set:{
        firstName : req.body.firstName,
        lastName : req.body.lastName, 
        email : req.body.email,
        phone : req.body.phone
      }},{new:true}) 
     .then((driver) => {
        if (driver) { //what was updated
          console.log(driver);
        } else {
          console.log("no data exist for this id");
        }
     })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
     });
 } else {
   console.log("please provide correct id");
 }

});
```

### RIDERS

```
//Placeholder until database conenction is live
app.get('/riders', (req, res, next) => {
  Rider.find()
 .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
 //if error, send internal server error
 .catch(err => {
 console.log('Error: ${err}');
 res.status(500).json(err);
});
});

// serve incoming post requests to /riders
app.post('/riders', (req, res, next) => {
  const rider = new Rider({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    homeAddress: req.body.homeAddress,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
    email: req.body.email

  });

app.put('/riders/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("id: " + req.params.id)

  if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
    Rider.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},
      {$set:{
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        homeAddress: req.body.homeAddress,
        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
        email: req.body.email
                  }},{new:true}) 
       .then((rider) => {
          if (rider) { 
            console.log(rider);
          } else {
            console.log("Data does not exist for this id");
          }
       })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
       });
   } else {
     console.log("please provide correct id");
   }

    //send the document to the database 
    rider.save()
    //in case of success
    .then(() => { console.log('New rider has been successfully uploaded to the database.');})
    //if error
    .catch(err => {console.log('Error:' + err);});

  }); 

})

app.delete("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
 Rider.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(result => {
   console.log(result);
   res.status(200).json("Deleted!");
 });
});

app.put('/riders/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("id: " + req.params.id)

  if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
    Rider.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},
      {$set:{firstName : req.body.firstName,
                 lastName : req.body.lastName,
                 homeAddress: req.body.homeAddress,
                 phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
                 email: req.body.email
                }},{new:true}) 
     .then((rider) => {
        if (rider) { 
          console.log(rider);
        } else {
          console.log("Data does not exist for this id");
        }
     })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
     });
 } else {
   console.log("please provide correct id");
 }

});  
//to use this middleware in other parts of the application
module.exports=app;
```

Comment: This isn't Angular. Fix your tags and title

Comment: it is in the app.js file built with Angular

Comment: Right now I am in Visual Code trying to figure out why this isn't working when it works for the listDrivers component

Comment: this is AngularJS, not Angular 2+ , right?

Comment: Yes Angular JS app

Comment: Change your password, you left it public (I removed it now)

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: No errors, because at least that would give breadcrumbs